# How do I open .as files in Xcode 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, xcode, xcode4

Is there a way to force Xcode to recognize .as (ActionScript 3) files as source code? If I right click the file in the files and folders side bar I can only "Open As.." Preview or Hex.

If I rename the file extension to something Xcode knows (.m), Xcode allows editing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I don't think you'll get Actionscript syntax highlighting in XCode, and you won't be able to compile your code from there.

Comment: @Marc, hey, yes, you **can** actually compile Actionscript from Xcode, given you have the Flex SDK and you set up your target to build with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to open your .as file in xcode4 editor and edit it? If yes, you can do it by following steps

1. Select your .as file
2. View -> Utilities -> File Inspector
3. Change the File type of your file(say change it to "Plain Text")

Now if you select you file and right click on it and choose "Open As", you will get 4 options(
ASCII Property List, Hex, Preview and Source )

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This allowed me to edit the files inside Xcode 4.

Comment: You can choose 'javascript' and get some syntax highlighting.

Comment: I use Xcode 8 and unfortunately after closing it and reopening I have to change file types again.